# Quarkus: How to print logs in a specific color?

Tags: java, gradle, logging, quarkus, tput

I have a multi-module Gradle project with Quarkus services. I run them all together and I would like to be able to distinguish logs by color. I want different services print logs in different colors (so that I could distinguish them easily).

I am trying to use `tput` for that. Here is how I start a particular service:

```
tput setaf 1; ./gradlew -b submodule-name/build.gradle --console=plain
```

This is supposed to paint the output to red. It does it correctly for Gradle logs, but Quarkus logs seem to behave unpredictably. Sometimes they are painted, but more often they are not (with no changes in code).

**Question:** How to paint Quarkus logs in different colors? How to set the color dynamically?

I would appreciate any ideas to solve my issue (even if they don't answer my question).